# How to authorize dockerhub automated build to pull an image from a private repo?

Tags: dockerhub

I have a dockerhub account with private image repositories `priv1` and `priv2`. The base image for `priv1` is an image in `priv2`. For a long time, the automated build for `priv1` worked fine, but after a commit that contained no changes to `Dockerfile` or `.dockerignore`, the build started failing with:

```
2022-10-03T17:30:16Z #4 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/mycompany/priv2:tag
2022-10-03T17:30:16Z #4 ERROR: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

I never needed any authorization, since both repos belong to me.

Furthermore, if dockerhub asks for authorization to `priv2`'s **Bitbucket** repo, as opposed to its **dockerhub** repo, then the bad news is there is none since I manually push images to `priv2`. Is it possible there was a change in dockerhub, which now requires access to the source of the image used as base?

How can I grant this authorization? I crawled through every possible menu and found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved itself — or rather, the dockerhub devs solved it.